# Setar largura de JDialog de acordo com o tamanho das somas das colunas de uma tabela

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Tenho a soma da largura das colunas e preciso setar este valor de forma que não oculte partes das colunas e diminua a janela. Alguma sugestão?
 Criei um método que retorna a soma do tamanho das colunas.
 Ai fiz outro método pra somar este valor com a da janela.

```
 public void autoSetLargura(List<Integer> colunas){
            Integer soma = getTabelaUtils().setPreferredWidthJanelaColunas(colunas)  + 300;

            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(soma, 500));

 }



     public Integer setPreferredWidthJanelaColunas(List<Integer> lista) { 
     //seta as colunas e me retorna a soma delas.
                Integer somaColunas = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                    setPreferredWidthColuna(i, lista.get(i));
                    somaColunas +=lista.get(i);
                }
                return somaColunas;
     }
```

Estes são os métodos, usando o pack() ele redimensiona certo, porem eu tenho que fazer isso em todas as janelas do mesmo tipo, como o mesmo tem uma base, fazendo nesta base ela funcionaria para todas que a implementam.

Comment: Tem como você colocar o que já fez até agora? Acho que pode ajudar quem for responder.

Comment: Esse método (autoSetLargura) está dentro do seu JDialog? Se sim coloque o pack() após o preferredSize.